# sed- detecting exact length&multiplying words

Tags: regex, sed

A word is a sequence of characters with no spaces and no \n.
Write a script in sed which gets as a parameter a file name, 
the script outputs the lines in the file which contain exactly 4 words.
also,every line which matches the regex, it's first word has  to be multiplied.

For example F1 contains:

```
Hello hi 123
if a equals b
you
one abc two three four
dany uri four 123
```

And the script's file named P9.4 if we type P9.4 F1 the output will be

```
if if a equals b    
dany dany uri four 123
```

I've actually thought about a solution:

```
sed 's/\(^([ ]*[^ ]\+[ ]\+)[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]*$\)/\2&/' $1 >>tmp
```

I'm getting an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -nr '/^(\w+)\s+\1\s+(\w+\s*){3}$/p' file
if if a equals b
dany dany uri four 123
```

Comment: well, actually, what Iv'e done is this:                              

sed 's/\(^([ ]*[^ ]\+[ ]\+)[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]*$\)/\2&/' $1 >>tmp                                                         but this thing, gives an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 62: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS  thx!

Comment: That's nice, where did you find that code? It has nothing to do with your question at all, not even close. Do you understand a single character?